# A running bash script is hung somewhere. Can I find out what line it is on?

Tags: linux, debugging, bash

E.g. does the bash debugger support attaching to existing processes and examining the current state?

Or can I easily find out by looking at the bash process entries in /proc?  Is there a convenient tool to give line numbers in active files?

I don't want to have to kill and restart the process.

This is on Linux - Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 18):

I recently found myself in a similar position. I had a shell script that was not identifiable through other means (such as arguments, etc.)

There are ways to find out a lot more about a running process than you would expect.

Use `lsof -p $pid` to see what files are open, which may give you some clues. Note that some files, while "deleted", can still be kept open by the script. As long as the script doesn't close the file, it can still read and write from it - and the file still takes up room on the file system.

Use `strace` to actively trace the system calls used by the script. The script will read the script file, so you can see some of the commands as they are read prior to execution. Look for `read` commands with this command:

```
strace -p $pid -s 1024
```

This makes the commands print strings up to 1024 characters long (normally, the `strace` command would truncate strings much shorter than that).

Examine the directory `/proc/$pid` in order to see details about the script; in particular note, see `/proc/$pid/environ` which will give you the process environment separated by nulls. To read this "file" properly, use this command:

```
xargs -0 -i{} < /proc/$pid/environ
```

You can pipe that into `less` or save it in a file. There is also `/proc/$pid/cmdline` but it is possible that that will only give you the shell name (`-bash` for instance).

Comment: +1 for answering the question. When debugging an already running script that might have a very sporadic issue which you cannot reproduce, another simple command you can use is `top` - you might find the process or its child taking up a lot of CPU, which could indicate an infinite loop.

Comment: +1 for very useful info. For me, `cat /proc/$pid/environ` gives me a bunch of squished up results, but `xargs -0 -i{} < /proc/$pid/environ` only gives 156 blank lines. The OS is CentOS release 6.7.

Comment: Same, also got blank lines. This works for me:
xargs -0 -n 1 echo < /proc/${pid}/environ

Comment: The `xargs` trick is neat, but the `echo` should not be required to make it work - the default behavior of `xargs` is to print its input. Maybe try removing the `-i{}` instead, or equivalently `tr '\0' '\n' <file`

Answer (score 12):

No real solution. But in most cases  a script is waiting for a child process to terminate:

```
ps --ppid  $(pidof yourscript)
```

You could also setup signal handlers in you shell skript do toggle the printing of commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap "set -x" SIGUSR1
trap "set +x" SIGUSR2

while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

Then use

```
kill -USR1 $(pidof yourscript)
kill -USR2 $(pidof yourscript)
```

Comment: True.  And your example with pidof is nice!  But I suggest the -x option since I'm talking about shell scripts, and more info from ps:  ps efl --ppid  $(pidof -x yourscript)

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar; now I know about the `--ppid` option.  Thanks.

Comment: Really cool solution. Better than launching the whole script with `bash -x`. I'll use this

Answer (score 6):

Use `pstree` to show what linux command/executable your script is calling. For example, `21156` is the pid of my hanging script:

```
ocfs2cts1:~ # pstree -pl 21156
activate_discon(21156)───mpirun(15146)─┬─fillup_contig_b(15149)───sudo(15231)───chmod(15232)
                                       ├─ssh(15148)
                                       └─{mpirun}(15147)
```

So that, I know it's hanging at `chmod` command. Then, show the stack trace by:

```
ocfs2cts1:~ # cat /proc/15232/stack 
[<ffffffffa05377ef>] __ocfs2_cluster_lock.isra.39+0x1bf/0x620 [ocfs2]
[<ffffffffa053856d>] ocfs2_inode_lock_full_nested+0x12d/0x840 [ocfs2]
[<ffffffffa0538dbb>] ocfs2_inode_lock_atime+0xcb/0x170 [ocfs2]
[<ffffffffa0531e61>] ocfs2_readdir+0x41/0x1b0 [ocfs2]
[<ffffffff8120d03c>] iterate_dir+0x9c/0x110
[<ffffffff8120d453>] SyS_getdents+0x83/0xf0
[<ffffffff815e126e>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x12/0x6d
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Oh, boy, it's likely a deadlock bug...

Comment: Yes, it's a kernel deadlock. I've fixed it :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've combined several answers from this thread.

- First you need to determine the process id, lets say **script_which_hangs.sh** script hanged, simply filter ps by the name of the script/process etc

```
> ps -ef | grep script_which_hangs
sos      1464260 1349476  0 14:08 ?        00:00:00 bash /repo/scripts/script_which_hangs.sh
sos      1464652 1316191  0 14:08 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto script_which_hangs
```

- Then I get its PID **1464260** from above output.

```
DPID=1464260; pstree -pal ${DPID}; lsof -p ${DPID}; pstree -pl ${DPID}
```

- first **pstree** show tree including all arguments (quite long output),
- then **lsof** shows open files,
- and last **pstree** prints the tree but without arguments so it is more readable for quick overview of situation

And just see the output, execute it again/again to see if anything changes. Potentially it might be extended for some method of current CPU/MEM but I've not looked for any command like that.

**pstree** has also **-s** parameter for including parents but it's rather not useful